# If the diphthong 'or' as or in 'more' followed by a vowel in the middle of the word，should we separate them as o-r+vowel?

Tags: pronunciation

When I listened to audiobook ***Anything You Want***, the recordist pronounces the word 'horrible' as [/ˈhȯr-ə-bəl/](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/horrible). But I was told that when there is a vowel after /r/ sound and the /r/ sound should go with the vowel after it. Then it should be /ˈhȯ-rə-bəl/, and the diphthong ȯr should be separated. like the word **[terrible](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/terrible)**, it has two ways to pronounce it. One is \ˈter-ə-bəl\ and the other is  \ˈte-rə-bəl.

So what is the common practice to separate the actual pronunciation syllables, when /r/ sound appears between two vowels? like horrible is a 3-syllable word, and it separated as hor-ri-ble. But for the phonetic syllable (IPA)/'hɔrəbl/, how we should separate it when we pronounce it /'hɔ-rəbl/ or /'hɔr-əbl/?

Comment: Are you trying to learn American or British English? They are completely different in this respect.

Comment: american english

Comment: Well ... whoever told you that when there is a vowel after the /r/ sound, the /r/ sound should go with the vowel after it was describing British English.

Comment: @PeterShor So what if the /r/ sound followed by a vowel sound within a word? Is there a linking between them? For example, Lorry is a two-syllable word lor-ry, and which r is pronounced, the fist one or the second one? As what you said, the first r should be pronounced in American English, and it should be /'lɔr-i/  in k.k. phonetic system. All I want to know is that after pronouncing the first syllable /'lɔr/, the tongue tip is curving up to make the /r/ sound, but when I keep pronouncing the /i/ sound is it like /ri/ or just /i/.

Comment: I really don't understand the question you're asking. There's nothing (no pauses or anything like that) in between the /r/ sound and the following /i/.